# Как забиндить включение и выключение автокликера?

Tags: python, циклы

Есть автокликер пробелом, нужно сделать так, чтобы, к примеру, на F8 включался скрипт, но не входил в работу. При повторном нажатии - выключался. Если так нельзя, то на F7 включение, F8 выключение.

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        while keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            sleep (0.06)
            keyboard.send('space')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я написал скрипт, запускаю его, зажимаю пробел - пробел начинает кликаться с большей скоростью, чем обычно. Отпускаю - перестает. Выключаю скрипт - работа завершена. Мне нужно создать программу со множествами скриптами, для включения скрипта, код которого я оставил - нужно нажать какую-нибудь клавишу. Т.е если программа открыта, но не включен скрипт - он не работает, если зажать пробел, то будет как без скрипта. Если я включу по кнопке и после уже зажму пробел - скрипт будет работать. надеюсь понятно? Активацию функции программы нужно сделать.